# Python, Printing from a text file and putting it in 1 line?

Tags: python

Ive been trying to work out how to put a text file randomly picks a word and prints it all in 1 line from 3 different text files which is done but I cant put it in 1 line? its put it in a new line each time? the words are all in columns in the text files. HEADS UP IM USING PYTHON IDLE!!

```
###############
import random 
import time    #Importing so some bits of code works
import sys    
###############

#The main game and generator
def main():

    #Gets text files from the folder and randomly picks a line of the text
    with open("column1.txt") as A:
        A = random.choice(list(A))
    with open("column2.txt") as B:
        B = random.choice(list(B))
    with open("column3.txt") as C:
        C = random.choice(list(C))

    print("\nThou\n"A+B+C)

    time.sleep(2)

    print("Restarting...\n")

    menu()

#Menu System
def menu():
    print("===Menu===")
    print("Choose 1 to start the abuse generator.")
    print("Choose 2 to exit.")
    choice = input("Please choose one: ")

    if choice == "1":
       main()

    elif choice == "2":
        sys.exit()

    else:
        print("Error!")

#Go's to the menu that is defined as menu above
menu()
```

This is the output:

```
===Menu===
Choose 1 to start the abuse generator.
Choose 2 to exit.
Please choose one: 1

Thou
 lumpish
  tdizzy-eyed
  thugger-mugger

Restarting...
```

Here is column1:

```
artless
bawdy
beslubbering
bootless
churlish
cockered
clouted
craven
currish
dankish
dissembling
droning
errant
fawning
fobbing
froward
frothy
gleeking
goatish
gorbellied
impertinent
infectious
jarring
loggerheaded
lumpish
mammering
mangled
mewling
paunchy
pribbling
puking
puny
quailing
rank
reeky
roguish
ruttish
saucy
spleeny
spongy
surly
tottering
unmuzzled
vain
venomed
villainous
warped
wayward
weedy
yeasty
```

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the formatting of the files? Can we see the layout of column1.txt?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Sounds like you need to split your files into strings on the new line character:

```
with open("column1.txt") as A:
    A = random.choice(A.read().split('\n'))
with open("column2.txt") as B:
    B = random.choice(B.read().split('\n'))
with open("column3.txt") as C:
    C = random.choice(C.read().split('\n'))
```

You may also want to call the print statement differently so it adds spaces:

```
 print("\nThou\n", A, B, C)
```

For this to work python 2 you need to use `from __future__ import print_function` or omit the braces.

Comment: Just prints this?
Choose 1 to start the abuse generator.
Choose 2 to exit.
Please choose one: 1===Menu===
Choose 1 to start the abuse generator.
Choose 2 to exit.
Please choose one: 1

Thou
 lumpish
 /tdizzy-eyed
 /thugger-mugger
 /
Restarting...

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there is a syntax error:

```
print("\nThou\n"A+B+C)
```

should be

```
print("\nThou\n"+A+B+C)
```

Sample code:

```
A = "Some random Text1"
B = "Some random Text2"
C = "Some random Text3"
print("\nThou\n",A,B,C)
```

output:

```
Thou
Some random Text1 Some random Text2 Some random Text3
```

Please let me know if you have any other question on this

Comment: This would not work as I am trying to print it from a text file which is done but I want it to be on the same line as each other and all it does is put it on a new line in the output?

Comment: You can simply put them in `print()` with comma seperated to print all of them in a single line

Comment: ?! Im printing it from a .txt file? and printing it with a , instead of a + is the same? All im trying to do is put it in the same line

Comment: That's because you still have linebreaks from reading the file. Look at my answer below to see how to remove them.

Answer (score 0):

To put multiline strings on one line, you can do

```
with open("column1.txt") as A:
    A = random.choice(list(A))
with open("column2.txt") as B:
    B = random.choice(list(B))
with open("column3.txt") as C:
    C = random.choice(list(C))

print " ".join((A + B + C).splitlines())
```

`str.splitlines()` creates a list of strings, each being one line of a multiline string. Line breaks are removed, and multiple words on one line are not split().

Comment: Where would I put this (Sorry im new to python a bit)

Comment: I named the string object `mystring`, so just replace this with your variable name. I will clarify it in the answer.